# Can you request a literal value in graphql?

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to figure out how to mock requests when the client is ahead of the server.  I'd like to be able to just request literals so that I can go back and change them later, is there a way to do something like this?

```
query myQuery {
  type {
    fieldName: 42
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is quite easy to set up mock responses if you have at least the server boilerplate code set up. If you are using Apollo, there are built in tools to facilitate mocks.

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/mocking.html

From the docs:

> The strongly-typed nature of a GraphQL API lends itself extremely well
>   to mocking. This is an important part of a GraphQL-First development
>   process, because it enables frontend developers to build out UI
>   components and features without having to wait for a backend
>   implementation.

Here is an example from the docs:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema, addMockFunctionsToSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import { graphql } from 'graphql';

// Fill this in with the schema string
const schemaString = `...`;

// Make a GraphQL schema with no resolvers
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: schemaString });

// Add mocks, modifies schema in place
addMockFunctionsToSchema({ schema });

const query = `
query tasksForUser {
  user(id: 6) { id, name }
}
`;

graphql(schema, query).then((result) => console.log('Got result', result));
```

> This mocking logic simply looks at your schema and makes sure to
>   return a string where your schema has a string, a number for a number,
>   etc. So you can already get the right shape of result. But if you want
>   to use the mocks to do sophisticated testing, you will likely want to
>   customize them to your particular data model.